# How to use android fingerprint API to read all the fingerprints?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

Am developing an android application that will be used in a single device to register all the employee with their fingerprint and to send the data back to the da.

I have developed an application as Guided [Here](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-add-fingerprint-authentication-to-your-android-app-747304/) which can read the fingerprint. But it can only read fingerprints which were previously registered in the device.

How can i make it read all the employee fingerprints so as i can post it back to the databases?

Comment: Cache the data. Though the strategy might vary depending on your app and requirements.

Comment: @Enzokie,  please i need your help on this you have closed my importatnt question

Comment: @Enzokie open my question please i need a help on this

Comment: add more details to the question then I will vote to reopen however It needs 4 more people's vote.

Comment: Please @Adriaan vote my question to open am in need of help please

Comment: help me now if you can close any question which you don't have answers on it

Comment: I have changed the question. an you please open it up so i i get get the solution of my problem @Makyen

Comment: @Yvette @Colomb♦

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you have to cache your database inside android device.
Just put your database in the correspond directory.

You can use both shared preferences and SQLite queries. It depends on size of the database and other parameters .

Comment: THanks @Vyacheslav but my database is very large is for media communication Industry , Is it possible to save it all in the sqlite? ?

Comment: How much is it?Of course you can . But do you really want to write your own sync system? I would suggest to try to use firebase database .it easy works for both online and offline .

Comment: the app will have only one admin and all the others will be use it to read the infomation posted. And no input from app just is from my admin console.It seems like the firebase work with the data which inported from the app. Is it still possible to use firebase on this

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preference

to store values in shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("UserID","ABC");
editor.apply();
```

to retrieve values from shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String name = preferences.getString("Name", "");
if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
    name = name + "  XYZ";  /* Edit the value here*/
}
```